# Flutter Html Change Color of Number of Ordered List Items

Tags: html, flutter, dart, flutter-html

I want to change the color from the number of the items of the OrderedList . But I do not find a way to do this.

I can set the list style to example dots or numbers like in the following code example, but I can not find a way to change the color:

```
Html(
data: "<ol><li>Item 1</li><li>Item2</li></ol>",
 style: {
 "li": Style(
  listStyleType: ListStyleType.fromWidget(Padding(
   child: CircleAvatar(radius: 2,´
 backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 50, 50),)))),, },),
```

If I do not override the default styling the numbers stay black even when I change the color of the text itself.

Comment: Apparently this is fixed in flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6